# Do I have to make another account for the SE site?

Tags: support

I have an Stack overflow and Puzzling account that I made with google, but when I use google to log into SE, it says that this google account is new, and that if I already have an account, to click here, but then it just sends me to the start. Sorry if this isn't the right place to post this, but I don't know where else.

Comment: Each separate StackExchange site requires a separate login.  You should be given the option to log in using your existing SE credentials, so you don't need to create a new username and password for every site.

Comment: I’m logging in using google, but it says: “if you’re trying to associate a new open ID to an already existing account you’re in the wrong place”

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I believe that OpenID was being deprecated as a login method for SE.  You might need to choose a different login method.  Failing that, you're better off asking the question on meta.stackexchange.com, since it's not really relevant to this site in particular, and there are probably many people there who can give you a better answer.

Comment: First, I’m not sure how to normally log in to SE, that’s why I didn’t post it there.

Comment: If you go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login you should have the option of signing in via Facebook or Google, or of creating a username and password.  Failing that, try https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup and create a new account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy thing to do is just simply this: Click on ***network profile*** in top right corner of your profile! You should  end up at stack exchange network, with your user still signed in! Here's a screenshot to help: [image: profile pic]
Here's close up of the top right corner:

[image: in the top right]